# Problem with React Navigation 5 params passing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am new to react-native. I am trying to pass some data along with the navigation after successful API fetch.

```
 if (response.status === 200) {
    navigation.navigate(EditProfile, {
      password: password,
      address: 'Address',
      firstname: 'John',
      lastname: 'Doe',
    });
  }
```

in the receiving screen, according to the react navigation 5 I used "route" keyword to get the attached params. First of all I used

```
const {firstname} = route.params
```

it didn't worked so I tried logging the output of the params.

```
const EditProfile = ({route}) => {
console.log(route.params);
console.log(route);
return(someJSX)
```

output:

```
LOG      undefined
LOG      {"key": "EditProfile-eaMKo66zwdmYhxnS-uOdr", "name": "EditProfile", "params": undefined}
```

I am stuck in this since hours, help me
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try **hook useNavigation**, react-navigation Version: 5.x

```
// File SomeComponent.js
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  navigation.navigate('EditProfile', {
    password: password,
    address: 'Address',
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe',
  });
}

// File EditProfile.js
const EditProfile = ({ route }) => {
  const { password, address, firstname, lastname } = route.params;
  // do something with these values
}
```

Comment: You are not passing EditProfile as text. 
Make sure you have this in NavigationContainer:
<Stack.Screen name = "EditProfile" component = {EditProfile} />

Answer (score -1):

```
// set navigation params
const navigation = this.props.navigation;
        navigation.navigate(EditProfile, {
            password: password,
            address: 'Address',
            firstname: 'John',
            lastname: 'Doe',
        });


 
//receive navigation objects: try this
     this.props.navigation.getParam('password')
 or 
 // Access the  otherParam via Destructuring assignment
    const { otherParam } = this.props.route.params;
```

https://www.positronx.io/react-native-stack-navigator-passing-getting-params-to-screen/

Comment: Thank you sir, but its still not working, I am using React navigation 5,your solution is for previous versions. I have also tried functional component equivalent for this but still doesn't help.

Comment: have you refer this link?  " https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop ". Please refer under the navigation.navigate(name, params) "snack ". hope it will helps you..